# how to fix ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.unet_model'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to run ID Card Segmentation (MIDV-500) on my Ubuntu machine.
I need to run some files, and one of them is "train.py".
when i run "train.py" i get an error message on the Import section.

```
(the full repository - https://github.com/AdivarekarBhumit/ID-Card-Segmentation)
```

i try to import:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard, ModelCheckpoint
from .unet_model import get_model
```

the error on the Terminal:

```
/Downloads/ID-Card-Segmentation/model$ python train.py 
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .unet_model import get_model
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.unet_model'; '__main__' is not a package
```

how to fix that?

Comment: please try to remove the leading **.** so it becomes like this `from unet_model import get_model`

Comment: when i remove the "." it couse the following error --> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: can you put the error trace for the error you got after the suggestion from Feras? based on git hub `iou_loss.py train.py unet_model.py` are in the same level so there shd not be any need for `.`  if it's in python3 . also note that the code you are trying is  < tensor flow 2.0, so you will get more challenges once you resolve this error.

Comment: ~/Downloads/ID-Card-Segmentation/model$ python train.py 
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 5, in <module>
    from unet_model import get_model
  File "/home/tal/Downloads/ID-Card-Segmentation/model/unet_model.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .iou_loss import IoU
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package. @simpleApp

Comment: the problem now is inside **unet_model.py**, did you add that leading `.` in line 10 or was it there already? as @simpleApp mentioned, no need to use any `.`since both files are in the same level. mainly this `.` is used in **Django** frequently, but in  raw **Python** it is not, just being used in certain cases

Comment: thanks guys, that solve it. the "." was there already